# Copying files from XP to Vista in a bach file or command prompt

Tags: windows-vista

I am trying to setup a batch file to copy files from my XP laptop
to my Vista desktop on a workgroup network.

But I am getting a Access denied error. Same in a command prompt.

I can copy the files fine using Windows Explorer.

Any ideas please?

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've setup a share on Vista that you are accessing in XP.

In Vista, make the share accessible to everyone anonymously:

1. Right-click the folder you're sharing, and click Properties.
2. Click the Sharing tab, then Advanced Sharing
3. Click Permissions.
4. Click Add.
5. Under "Enter the object names to select", type "Everyone" (without quotes).
6. Click OK.
7. Select Everyone in the "Group or user names" box.
8. Under "Permissions for Everyone", check the Allow box for Full Control.
9. Click OK three times.

You should probably map that share as a network drive on your XP computer.

That should work.

EDIT: I have tested this with the exact same conditions you described, and it worked.

Comment: I tried that exactly as you say and it still does not work???
Anything else I should check?

Comment: Are you mapping the drive in XP with any credentials (username/password)?

If so, disconnect it, and map it again, this time without specifying any username or password.

Comment: No I just disconnected it and reconnected without credentials ...no good

Comment: When I look at the properties and security for Everyone on  XP for the connection it does not have full control....why?

Comment: I don't know, but that's definitely the source of your problem.  Maybe try reversing the process.  Share the folder you want on XP and run the batch file in Vista, copying the files from the share to the local folder.